# PHP Doesn't Execute Python Code

Tags: raspbian, gpio, pi-2

**led.py**

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(7,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(7,1)
time.sleep(5)
GPIO.output(7,0)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

index.html:   *(these 2 files are located in /var/www/html)*

```php5
<?php
        if(isset($_GET['on']))
{
                echo "on";
                exec("sudo python /var/www/html/led.py");
        }
        else if(isset($_GET['off'])){
                echo "off";
        }
?>
<html>
        <head>

        </head>
        <body>
                <form method="get">
                        <button name="on">on</button><br>
                        <button name="off">off</button><br>
                </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

I have tried system instead of exec.
I have added in etc/sudoers these 3 lines

```
pi ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
%www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/python /var/www/html/led.py
```

How can i fix this problem ?

Comment: Have you tried to enable debugging? What do the logs say? Did you really put `www-data` in the sudoers group? That seems dangerous...

Comment: Also, your `echo` command is missing a `;`.

Comment: hello jocobm001
i put a ;
but still its not working , it isnt calling led.py
how can i debug the pi ?

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) on stackoverflow. In addition, the logs under `/var/log/apache2` should tell you something.

Comment: Did that produce any noticeable results?

Comment: hello jacob thank you thats an important tip

this is what s inside log

192.168.1.9 - - [16/Feb/2017:10:24:08 +0000] "GET /?on= HTTP/1.1" 200 376 "http://192.168.1.5/?on=" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"

even if i press off i would get something similiar ...

i think the problem is about access..im still stuck